# Knockout BeforeRemove returns textNode not elementNode

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

When using Knockout's foreach binding, I'm trying to replicate the classing yellow fadein when an item is added to the list. (from [Here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html))

This is my code

```
<div id="minicartItems" data-bind="template: { foreach: DisplayItems, beforeRemove: ElementFadeOut, afterAdd: ElementFadeIn }">
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'sideCartItm' + $index() }">
            <!-- ko if: IsFleet() -->
                 <!-- DO STUFF -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: IsFleet() -->
                <!-- DO STUFF -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
</div>
```

And in my VM:

```
self.ElementFadeOut = function (element, index, data) {
    $(element).fadeOut();
    // $(element.id).fadeOut();   ADDING .ID  doesnt work either because its text node.
}

self.ElementFadeIn = function (element, index, data) {
    $(element)
        .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
        .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
}
```

However I'm getting errors on the console (and the fade isn't happening) when adding or removing items.

```
jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at Dt (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.css (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Gt (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.Gn (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Kn (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Text.o (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.dequeue (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Text.<anonymous> (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at init.each (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
```

From my investigation, it appears that the `element` parameter is not of type element, its of type textnode.

Here's a snapshot of `element` in the debugger:

[image]

If I expand `parentNode` and then `child nodes` I can see that there are text and div nodes, but I'm not sure why.

[image]

How can I get the functions to send the element node, not the text node?

Comment: Do you wan't the entire list to fade in or each list item?

Comment: consider using afterRender, then the element may be there.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `afterRender` instead of `afterAdd` was the solution - DOM elements cannot be added until they are rendered! http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove